# How do you find the similarity of tuples, as a fraction, in python?

Tags: python, tuples, similarity

For instance, if I had the tuples (1,2) and (3,2) in python, is there any way to have a program return 0.5 or 1/2? I've searched but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: "Similarity" here is defined as what precisely? That is to say, does order matter? Will the lengths of the tuples be the same?

Comment: Just compare the corresponding fields, then it's just a matter of taking the ratio of what's the same and the total...

Comment: Agree with @Charmander - could you please clarify what you mean...

Comment: Ahh thanks to @F.J I get it now... the OP wants to know what fraction of the tuples elements are the same

Comment: Sorry, yes I was wondering how to find what fraction of the elements are the same

Comment: @user1575060 -- does order matter?  for example, `a=(1,2); b=(2,1)`.  Do they have a similarity of 0 or 1?

Comment: To the answers involving zipping and comparing the values - consider if the order is different i.e. (2,1), (3,2)...

Comment: @mutzmatron -- Yeah, I was wondering that too.  I just asked a clarification of the OP on that.

Comment: @mgilson: Also what about duplicate values?

Comment: @mutzmatron -- *shrugs* I have no idea ... I think this problem could use a few more constraints :).

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear earlier - My goal is comparing only the nth term of the first tuple to the nth term of the second one, so (1,2) and (2,1) should return 0. F. J's assumption was correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> b = (3, 2)
>>> sum(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b)) / float(len(a))
0.5
```

The `float()` call is only necessary on Python 2.x, to avoid the integer division.  Alternatively you could use `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file.

Comment: What should happen in the case of `a = (1, 2); b = (2, 1)`?  Your answer will return 0, but I'm not sure if it should be 1 ...

Comment: @mgilson - Yeah, I interpreted as only comparing elements at the same index, will need some clarification from OP.

Comment: I think this works: My goal is comparing only the nth term of the first tuple to the nth term of the second one, so (1,2) and (2,1) should return 0. Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier

Comment: Thank you for your help guys :) I'm pretty new to python, so sorry if this was somewhat basic.

Answer (score 1):

For a general pair of tuples you probably need to use `set`:

```
similarity = float(len(set(a).intersection(set(b))))/len(a)
```

Of course using `len(a)` demonstrates that the 'similarity' is relational and needs to be better defined.

In this case I have answered the question: *What fraction of elements in a are also in b?*

Comment: I believe there is a part missing in your answer.

Comment: @mutzmatron -- See clarification in comments on answer by F.J

Comment: @mgilson: Yeah just saw - I was worried about a more general question. Ahh well!

Comment: This is a nice answer but it ignores the ordering of the tuples. depending on the application, (A,B) != (B,A)